# How to set max window size and prevent resizing in flutter desktop?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have seen this package [desktop_window](https://pub.dev/packages/desktop_window) which lets me to set the size for what I want, but It doesn't tell me the max size of the window that can fit on the screen, and I don't know also how to lock the window size to the max size. How can I do that? I need it to work on linux and windows.

note: I tried this code inside `main` using the above package, but doesn't work:
`await DesktopWindow.setMinWindowSize(Size.infinite);`

Comment: You're gonna love [MediaQuery](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html)!

Comment: @plotsklapps I don't understand how this helps?